# How to calculate the dice score between 3 images?

Tags: python, image, metrics, image-segmentation

I have always seen functions that take 2 images as input to calculate their dice score. How should I expand this to calculate the dice score between 3 images? I am actually trying to find out how similar 3 given images are. I have tried considering any one image to be the ground truth and calculated the dice score between that and the other 2.

So for example I have 3 images A, B, and C. I consider A to be the ground truth then I can calculate the dice score between A and B; A and C and then similarly between B and C. Now I need to calculate the dice score between all 3 images A, B, and C. Is there a method to calculate this value?

Comment: Dice score is the percentage of similarity between 2 images. It doesn't make sense to define it for 3 images. For example, what would a score of 0.5 mean?

Comment: Also, what's wrong with calculating dice between `(A,B)`, `(B,C)` and `(C,A)` separately? That's perfectly defined and has a meaning.

Comment: You could heuristically extend it to be 3(A int B int C)/(A + B + C), but why not just compare B and C to A independently? Why should B and C be compared to each other?

Comment: @CaptainTrojan yes it's fine to calculate between (A,B), (B,C), and (C,A) separately, I was just wondering if there is a method to do so between all 3 at once.